# Min, Max, Mean program in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to construct a program that will take a users positive input for number of values then scan for the users values and state those values (which can be negative), but if the user enters any letters the program is supposed to skip over them in the list of values. I also can't figure out how to have the program skip over a negative number for the number of values if accidentally inputed (in the first example -4 is accidentally inputed for number of values and skipped, then 4 is used for number of values followed by each value). I would appreciate the help!

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
int i;
double userVal;
double userNum;
double min = 0;
double max = 0;
double sum = 0;
double average;

scanf("%lf", &userVal);

for (i = 1; i <= userVal; ++i) {

    scanf("%lf", &userNum);
    sum += userNum;
    
    if (i == 1 || min > userNum)
        min = userNum;
    
    if (i == 1 || max < userNum)
        max = userNum;
}
average = sum / userVal;

printf("The minimum value is %g, the maximum value is %g, and the average value is %g.\n", 
min, max, average);
return 0;
}
```

Picture of output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q4YC.png

Comment: For the letters, check the return value from `scanf`. It is the number of successful scans. If it is not `1` then read the entire line and discard.

Comment: Discard with `%*[^\n]%*c`.

Comment: Your average is wrong, it's `sum / count`, not `sum / userVal`.

Comment: @Blindy `userVal` is the count. Not a great variable name, and it should probably be an integer, but whatever!

Comment: Use "while(!scanf("%lf", &userVal) && userVal < 0) ;" for scanning userVal

Comment: A bit off topic but you can initialize `min` with a very high number and `max` with a very low number (min/max of the type you are using) and dont have to check for the iteration you are in when overriding it

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) use the return from `scanf`. It returns the number of successful scans. It also returns EOF if there was an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

// helper function to read all characters up to and including a new line
void consume_line()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        // Error??
        if (c == EOF) {
            // Handle error. Maybe exit program?
            puts("ERROR");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int count;
    double min = DBL_MAX;
    double max = DBL_MIN;
    double sum = 0;

    do {
        // Read an int. If failure, discard input
        if (scanf("%d", &count) != 1) {
            consume_line();
            count = -1;
        }
    } while (count <= 0);  // Loop until count > 0

    int count2 = count;  // Use a copy since count is needed later
    while (count2 > 0) {
        double userNum;
        if (scanf("%lf", &userNum) == 1) {
            // Success
            sum += userNum;
            count2--;
            if (min > userNum) min = userNum;
            if (max < userNum) max = userNum;
        }
        else {
            // Failure
            consume_line();
        }
    }

    double average = sum / count;
    printf("The minimum value is %g, the maximum value is %g, and the average value is %g.\n", 
min, max, average);
    return 0;
}
```